# Sharing one TFS login among several people

Tags: tfs

We are using a TFS account among few developers to develop a web application in .NET. Is it possible sharing one TFS login among several people? If so, which problems I will face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will lose all traceability in your project. You can't see who made a change, picked up a task or asked for a review.

You also won't be able to set any security restrictions. Since all users are the same, everyone will be able to do everything.

In addition to those practical issues, sharing a TFS account with multiple people will get you into [licensing issues](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350).

I would strongly urge you to reconsider sharing an account. The cost benefit of having to buy only one account makes you loose so much in TFS fuctionality that it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want a version control system if you are making multiple developers share one account. You will loose a lot of data that would have otherwise being important. For example, assigning tasks, bugs, tracking progress and many more to do with management.

In terms of code management it would be possible yet very cramped and disorganised with no way to discuss troublesome merges, since you don't know who did it. :)